# Why is first text view in list empty when populating the list from SQLite Database?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I am populating a list from an SQLite database which works fine but the first text view is always empty and I cannot figure out why. This is causing me issues because I use the populated text views to display information when clicked but as the first one is empty and can be clicked it is causes the program to fail. Here is my code:

```
public class ShowPhrases extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

SQLiteDatabase database;
NotesDbAdapter md;
CursorAdapter dataSource;
 TextToSpeech tts;


private static final String fields[] = { "phrase", "folang",BaseColumns._ID };

NotesDbAdapter.DatabaseHelper helper = new NotesDbAdapter.DatabaseHelper(
        this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hs);

    //Set volume buttons to music volume instead of ringer
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor data = database.query("notes", fields, null, null, null, null,null);


    dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.highscores, data, fields, new int[] { R.id.first });

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    lv.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
    lv.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.highscores, null));

    lv.setAdapter(dataSource);
```

The highscores xml layout:

```
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textColor="#357ae8"
    android:textSize="20dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The hs xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gerback"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: Where are you using that first xml layout? Is that R.layout.highscores? You are also missing a chunk of the xml there. You are also using a deprecated constructor for SimpleCursorAdapter, one which is performed on the UI thread.

Comment: Hi I edited my question to make it clearer. Yes the first xml is highscores, the second is hs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor data = database.query("notes", fields, null, null, null, null,null);

data.moveToNext();

dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.highscores, data, fields, new int[] { R.id.first }, 0);
```

Does it works?

Remember to add `0` as last parameter to use the non deprecated method.

Comment: Hi there I tried your answer but still the list is loaded with the first list populates with an empty text view then the first list item underneath. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

When you say that the first Textview is empty, are you talking about the headerview or the first item in the list?

If you mean the headerview, and the first piece of xml (in your question) is the one being inflated into it (R.layout.highscores), then the problem is simply that you haven't assigned it any text to display. The headerview isn't populated by the adapter, and it scrolls with the list, so it will be blank in your case.

Comment: Hi there, when I load a fresh install of the app and go to the list there is an empty text view at the top of the activity and nothing underneath, when I add data to the SQLite database then go to the list activity and it it is populated from this data the first piece of data is added to a text view underneath the empty text view. Thanks a lot!